# How can I implement a code to fix a label in WPF?

Tags: wpf, position, label

I'm dealing with a subsonic nozzle simulator and I am in trouble because if I change the height of the label, consequently the position of the label is changed.

I want to fix this position with code and be able to change the altitude without any effect.

The code is below:

```
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                {
                    System.Windows.Controls.Label lbl = new System.Windows.Controls.Label();
                    lbl.Height = Areas[j] * 30;
                    lbl.Width = rejilla.Width / columns;


                    lbl.Tag = new Point(1, j); 


                    lbl.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
                    lbl.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);



                    if (nozzleQ1D.ColorCeldaPresion(Pressures[j]) == "Black")
                        lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                    if (nozzleQ1D.ColorCeldaPresion(Pressures[j]) == "Firebrick")
                        lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Firebrick);
                    if (nozzleQ1D.ColorCeldaPresion(Pressures[j]) == "Red")
                        lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    if (nozzleQ1D.ColorCeldaPresion(Pressures[j]) == "Orange")
                        lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                    if (nozzleQ1D.ColorCeldaPresion(Pressures[j]) == "Yellow")
                        lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
                    if (nozzleQ1D.ColorCeldaPresion(Pressures[j]) == "Green")
                        lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    if (nozzleQ1D.ColorCeldaPresion(Pressures[j]) == "Cyan")
                        lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);
                    if (nozzleQ1D.ColorCeldaPresion(Pressures[j]) == "Blue")
                        lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
                    if (nozzleQ1D.ColorCeldaPresion(Pressures[j]) == "Purple")
                        lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);
                    if (nozzleQ1D.ColorCeldaPresion(Pressures[j]) == "Indigo")
                        lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Indigo);


                    stkPanel.Children.Add(lbl);
                }


                rejilla.Children.Add(stkPanel);
```

Comment: Just a note, instead of that long chain of if-statements, use a switch statement. Also replace `lbl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)` by `lbl.Background = Brushes.Black` etc. Even better: `lbl.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(nozzleQ1D.ColorCeldaPresion(Pressures[j]))` without any if or switch statement.

Comment: The problem is probably your layout configuration. You are using StackPanel with an unknown orientation and content alignment. If alignment is Center for your labels, then their position will change when you change their size. Try to align somewhere.